# swift attribute from another attribute of the same entity

Tags: swift, core-data, attributes, entity, relationship

I have an entity (core data) named **Image**, which contains two attributes: **name, url** (both strings).

At a certain stage of my code I'm populating an array (named **searchResults**) through a textfield with some of the same names stored in core data (Image) (so **some .name attributes**).

What i'm trying to do is to get from the database respective .url attributes for each .name attribute, but only for those .name present in the aforementioned array.

I excluded a dictionary from two arrays cause from what i know the keys of dictionary must be unique elements (and that wouldn't be my case), I've read some documentations about predicates but i'm not sure if that is the right path, seems like they're made more for multiple entities than for what i'm looking for.. my problem should be simpler than that but i can't find how to do it

Comment: Why don't you create an array of dictionaries (or tuples) containing name and url, when filtering?

Comment: Or build an array of Image objects whose name attribute meets your criteria, rather than storing just the names.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, i'm not sure whether i can go for an array tho, since the Image attributes are randomly added and updated by the user

Comment: Also, in that array i need to have only names due to the fact i'm using a searchbar for names, it's basically a collection view with searchbar but unlike the projects/tutorials i found on the web, i'm showing images through urls, not simple by using image names where images are static inside the project

Comment: It's possible to fetch from CoreData just the url attribute, and (using a predicate) to limit the fetch to just certain names.  But this might not be the best solution.  It will help if you post the code for populating `searchResults`, and the `collectionView` datasource methods.

Comment: I solved creating a Dictionary with the two Arrays, using Names as keys fetching for urls, seems it works fine! since the name field is optional in my app I had to save a string like "unknown" if field is left empty and adding an incremental Int to it so everytime it gets like unknown1, unknown2, etc (this just for a searchbar purpose since was not creating errors otherwise), thanks all for your help